# Values disappear from ng-options when setting a default value

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-options` to build my `<select>` and `ng-model` to populate my default value from my data, but when I select an item after the list loads they all disappear. I need to have a default value set when the window loads. I had to use `track by` because it kept putting **'number: 1'** in front of my `value`. I'm binding my ID and text

```
<select name="myStatusID" ng-model="vm.selectedStatus" ng-options="myStatus.value as myStatus.text for myStatus in vm.statusList track by myStatus.value"></select>
```

`vm.selectedStatus` is being set by the detail record coming back so I get a default value in my angular controller.

```
vm.selectedStatus = { value: value[0].selectedStatus };
```

Comment: Could you create [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The line where are setting `vm.selectedStatus` looks weird, too. You are setting it to an object with a single `value` property set to the first element in an array of `selectedStatus` named `value`? Maybe use different variable names so it's not so confusing.

Comment: I think what you want for ng-options is "myStatus as myStatus.text for myStatus in vm.statusList track by myStatus.value".  Your vm.selectedStatus should then point to a complete record, not a record with just a value in it. vm.selectedStatus = { value: 1, text: "One"} and presumabley vm.statusList is an array of things like the selectedStatus